# Jest github action on docker-compose socket hang up AND connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.7:3000

Tags: node.js, docker, jestjs, github-actions

In my nodeJs api, I'm using Jest to run test and when deploying anything on github, we have an automatic docker-compose action that trigger the npm run test.

We are creating the request object like that :

```
  baseURL: `http://${host}:3000`,
  timeout: 10000,
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-API-KEY': '****',
  },
})
```

Then I have a special file for all my user request, for exemple signUp request is like that :

```
const { request } = require('./requests')

async function signUp(data, config) {
  return await request.post('/users/sign-up', data, config)
}
```

And my Jest test :

```
test('Should sign-up a new user', async () => {
  const data = {...}
  const config = { headers: {... } }
  const response = await signUp(data, config)
  expect(response.status).toEqual(200)
})
```

Locally the test are passing. And it was also working on github action, but from around a week it stopped to work and I can't find the reason.

Here are the error that the test return when running on github :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNBe2.png)

I'm getting 'socket hang' up AND 'connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.7:3000' error. Nothing has been changed regarding test so do you know what can cause those issues ?

Comment: Is there any update on that? I am facing the same issues ...
Were you able to resolve it?